# I can't open the Django admin site on my Pydroid3

Tags: python, django-admin

I can't open the Django admin site on my Pydroid3 app

After I had finished creating the Django project, I then run Python manage.py runserver. That work, but when I try to open the admin site I instead, got this on the web browser [the error message I got on the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpqd9.png)

Moreover I got this on the terminal [the error message I got on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qif6P.png).

Comment: Please post your error message and traceback as text, no screenshots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.